# Chrome Extension - case insensitive content script matches

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my manifest I am injecting some content scripts based on a specific page name.

However it appears that the matching is case sensitive, so it matches example.html but not Example.html.

How can I make it not case sensitive?

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/example.html"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 6):

You have probably figured that out by now, but there is **no** way to apply a match pattern *case-insensitively*. According to the **[docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html)**, the Match Patterns do not support regular expressions (only **[globs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)**, a.k.a. pattern matching using wildcard characters).

So, you need to explicitely enter the different variation (e.g. `http://*/example.html` and `http://*/Example.html`)

Alternatively, you could use the `include_globs` element, e.g. allowing all paths starting with any letter followed by "xample", but this will also allow paths like `.../Axample.html` etc, so it might probably not fit your purpose.

```
{
    "matches": ["http://*/*.html"],
    "include_globs": ["http://*/?xample.html"]
    ...
```

See, also, the documentation about **[Match Patterns and globs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#match-patterns-globs)**